# How to iterate over object properties?

Tags: javascript

I'd like if possible parse an angularJS model. Thats means, for each properties check one by one (in a loop) if the value of this property make an action if not make a different action.

I can do this in C# but don't know if possible in this language.

```
var customer = {
    FirstName: "",
    LastName: "MyLastName",
    Email: "",
};
```

Thanks,

Comment: do you mean loopontg throth model in themplate?

Comment: you want to loop through a js object? if yes, take a look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var customer = {
    FirstName: "",
    LastName: "MyLastName",
    Email: "",
}; 

for(var propertyName in customer) {
   var propertyValue = customer[propertyName];
   console.log('LIST PROPERTIES: ', propertyName, propertyValue);
   
   if(propertyName == "LastName" && propertyValue == "MyLastName") {
       // do something
       console.log('your ' + propertyName + ' is ' + propertyValue);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, using for(key in Obj) loop.

```
for(var propertyName in customer) {
   // you can get the value like this: $scope.customer[propertyName]
}
```

Comment: If using the for() loop, it's recommended to verify that $scope.customer.hasOwnProperty(propertyName) returns true to avoid getting unwanted inheriting properties.